# How can strips of light form from natural light coming through an insect net?

Tags: interference

This morning I noticed strips of light forming on a piece of paper. The only source of light was one window, with 1/3 of it open. So light was coming from either an insect screen or blurred glass. Also no direct sunlight because of tall buildings around.

When I lifted the paper so that the surface was orthogonal to the source of light, the strips became more dense.

The strips only appeared at a narrow range of distance (around $3\;\text{m}$ or $10\;\text{ft}$) from the window.

Only knowing high school physics, at first I thought it was light interference, but then the insect net is a grid, not slits! What is happening?

Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YguZh.jpg): more or less evenly spaced light strips with a vertical column of shadow in the center, which is probably from a security rod in my window (Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAUl8.jpg))

[image: strips of light appearing on paper, facing light source]

[image: window at the time of the event. I live in Seoul.]

Comment: Can you take a picture of the window as it was when you saw the pattern?

Comment: Is it a metal screen? I have just finished using some metal insect net, and although it is a grid , depending on way I hold it , one line direction is shiny,although intermitent , due to the grid. At what distance from the scree is the photo?

Comment: @MarkH I added a picture of the window. Thank you for showing interest!

Comment: @annav  The distance was around 3m(~10ft) and the screen is indeed metal, though extremely dusty. Thank you for showing interest!

Comment: A couple of close-up photos of the net from different angles might help.  The detailed shape of the holes and the wires could be the cause.